# Open set of geodesics implies the set of starting points is open

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, metric-spaces, borel-sets

Let $X$ be a complete and separable metric space, let $G(X) \subset C([0,1],X)$ be the space of continuous curves from $[0,1]$ to $X$ with constant speed, i.e.
$$ d(f(t),f(s)) = |t-s| d(f(0), f(1)). $$
Let $S : X^2 \rightarrow 2^{G(X)}$ be such that at every couple of points $(x,y)$ it associates a curve starting at $x$, i.e. $f(0) = x$, and ending at $y$, i.e. $f(1) = y$. We define the preimage of a set $T \subseteq G(X)$ through $S$ as
$$ S^{-1}(T) := \lbrace (x,y) \in X^2 : F(x,y) \cap T \neq \emptyset \rbrace. $$

It can be proven that $G(X)$ endowed with the distance
$$\delta(f,g) = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} d(f(x), g(x))$$
is still a complete and separable metric space.

Now take $A \subset G(X)$ an open set. Is $S^{-1} (\lbrace A \rbrace) $ an open set? Is it at least a Borel set?

---

Take now, in the same situation as before, $S : X^2 \rightarrow 2^{G(X)}$ s.t. at every couple of points $(x,y)$ it associates **all the curves** with constant speed starting at $x$, i.e. $f(0) = x$, and ending at $y$, i.e. $f(1) = y$.

In this situation is the preimage through $S$ of an open subset of $G(X)$ open or Borel in $X^2$?

Comment: Even if $X$ is the unit circle with path-metric then there is no continuous map $S$, therefore, preimages of open sets will not be in general open.

Comment: The question now makes less sense and should be edited: You have to explain which topology you put on the set of all subsets of $G(X)$ since your new map takes values not in $G(X)$ but in $2^{G(X)}$. If your topology is at all reasonable, the circle will provide a counter-example to the continuity question.

Comment: I'm not interested in a topology on $2^{G(X)}$, I'm taking $S$ open in $G(X)$.

Comment: Your map is $S: X^2\to 2^{G(X)}$, as you assign to $x,y$ the _set_ of all geodesics connecting $x$ and $y$, just read what is written in your post. How are you planning to define continuity if you have no topology on the target space?

Comment: @ User11111. If you have $S:X^2\rightarrow 2^{G(X)}$, then what do you mean by "preimage through $S$ of an open subset of $G(X)$" ?

Comment: @ User11111. If you have e.g. $X=\mathbb S^{\kern.5mm 1}$, for every open $A\subseteq G(X)$ the set of $(x,y)\in X^{\kern.5mm 2}$ with $S((x,y))\in\{A\}$, i.e $S((x,y))=A$ is the empty set, and hence is *trivially open*.

Comment: @Misha. For a multivalued mappping $S$ in this context $S^{-1}(A)$ is defined as $\{x \in X : S(x) \cap A \ne \emptyset\}$. The unit circle is still a counterexample to preimages being open. Asking for Borel might make more sense.

Comment: @TapioRajala: Dear Tapia, this makes more sense. Another interesting question is if for every $X$ _there exists_ a Borel map $S: X^2\to G(X)$. For instance, this is the case for Riemannian manifolds.

Comment: @Misha: It is an intereting question indeed. And the existence of a Borel selection is exactly where the current question was heading. If the multivalued mapping is Borel in the sense described above, then a Borel selection of geodesics immediately exists, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/145351/x-polish-geodesic-implies-p-2x-w-2-geodesic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It need not be even Borel. Take $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ with $d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) = \max(|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|)$. Then it is easy to construct a selection $S$ with $S^{-1}(A)$ not Borel for some open set $A$. (For example select for a suitable non-Borel set of doubles of points a non-Euclidean geodesic and for the rest a Euclidean one.)

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean exactly by "Euclidean" geodesic?

Comment: I mean a constant speed geodesic in the Euclidean distance $\sqrt{|x_1-y_1|^2+|x_2-y_2|^2}$ parametrized by the unit interval $[0.1]$.